Click lock is visible on some Luxury Vinyl Planks?
I have ordered samples of a few LVP / Luxury Vinyl Plank products.  Unfortunately the one that I most prefer for the color ( marble /white) apparently is not flush between the tiles: the click lock is visible.  The samples are shown below with the product in question marked by the red rectangle:

The visible/exposed portion of the click lock is 3/32":

Is this a thing? I mean I'd rather have the planks flush, but then should I be thinking about this in a different way ?
Update:
The HomeDepot flooring manager said these tiles should not have any gap. Apparently the samples do not properly attach to each other. He recommended getting one box to try it out "for real".

Is the gap intended to emulate a grout line?

@DanIsFiddlingByFirelight  It does seem to emulate it - which is a heavily negative attribute. I hate grout lines.

You have many choices of LVPs to choose from. It comes down to matter of taste, opinion and style. In the end you pick what you like from what is available.

It's all up to the design of the vinyl planks. Some attempt zero joint visibility whilst others make the joints provide a distinctive characteristic.
Some of the material that I have installed has beveled edges that show a contrasting color to the surface. Others there were small bevels at the tops of the joints but the colors blended very well with the surface. I believe that it is common that the top edges of these planks do have the beveled edges by design for two reasons:

The beveled edges eliminate the very sharp square corners of the plank that could easily be nicked of chipped.
The beveled edges at the plank seams tend to hide very tiny variations of plank thickness and tolerance on the click lock joints.


It is an interesting perspective: I have been wondering it the visibility were a design defect.  I had a call in to a flooring manager at the retail establishment (HomeDepot) and will see what they say as well.
